# Alternate argument lists of pure virtual won't inherit (needed "using")

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual

I've got a base class with a few pure virtuals, and I want it to provide default implementations of several methods which can be overridden if needed.  I've boiled my problem down to the following:

```
class A {};
class B {};

class Base {
public:
  virtual void foo (const A&) {};
  virtual void foo (const B&) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  virtual void foo(const B&) {};
};

int main(int argv, char** argc) {
  Derived d;
  d.foo(A());
  return 0;
}
```

For reasons I don't understand at all, this fails on g++ 4.8.2:

```
g++ scratch.cpp -o scratch
scratch.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
scratch.cpp:17:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘Derived::foo(A)’
   d.foo(A());
        ^
scratch.cpp:17:12: note: candidate is:
scratch.cpp:12:16: note: virtual void Derived::foo(const B&)
   virtual void foo(const B&) {};
            ^
scratch.cpp:12:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘A’ to ‘const B&’
```

If I define `foo(const B&)` in `Base` and leave `Derived` empty, the problem goes away.  I've read the docs and some of the questions here, but nothing has suggested why this would be a problem.  In my real code, `Base::foo(const A&)` will build a special object `b` of type `B` from the `A` object, and then call `foo(b)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your `Derived` class definition:

```
using Base::foo;
```

This will solve the problem that your foo(B) definition in Derived hides both foo(A) and foo(B) functions in Base.

Answer (score 0):

Within minutes, I find it.

I need `using Base::foo` in `Derived`.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/hiding-rule.html

Thank you StackOverflow once again for helping me answer my own question.  Couldn't have done it without you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot modify the base and/or derived class, and still want to call the (accessible) method, you may fully qualify the call:

```
Derived d;
d.Base::foo(A());
```

Comment: I don't think that's what I want.  I'm pretty sure that will force the `Base` implementation of `foo(const A&)` to get called, even if `Derived` overrides it.  I want to leave `Derived` the option to override with its own implementation or not.

Comment: Well, yes.. that makes sense!